# How can I transfer Dropbox file data to SQL Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ftp, dropbox

I'm getting files four days a week through my Dropbox folder and I need to add that data to my sql server. 
In the past I've been using FTP to transfer files, but I'm not sure if FTP will work with Dropbox and I don't know how to do it. 
I've had some experience with SSIS in the past and I'm pretty sure that SSIS could do this task, but I'm not able to add integration services extension to my SQL Server. 
Does anyone have any idea what would be the easiest way to transfer these files to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some third party components that allow you to read from Dropbox:

- [Kingswaysoft SSIS Dropbox Source Component](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-productivity-pack/help-manual/cloud-storage/dropbox-source-component)
- [CDATA - Dropbox SSIS Components](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/dropbox/ssis/)

Or you have to use an HTTP connection manager to download the file [using Dropbox api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs):

- http://www.sqlis.com/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx